# Meaning of "We get along just fine"

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> We get along **just fine**.

What does the above sentence mean?  I know the meaning of "get along well with somebody" but I have usually heard this phrase in sentences like

> I get along well with him

I am confused here with what does the speaker mean by saying "just fine" in "We get along just fine".

Comment: Hello, Singh. A friendly advice: To find definitions on Google, search for a word or phrase by including "define" before your search term. For example: [Define get along](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+get+along)

Comment: You can also +"meaning" in your search: "just fine meaning"

Answer (score 8):

In this sentence "just fine" means the same as "ok." It is slightly less positive than "well." It can also indicate that the person speaking is feeling defensive in response to the question.

Comment: Also note that, depending on the tone, it can mean that the relationship is not good. Though this applies to nearly everything when sarcasm is employed.

Comment: You can also use "just OK", a bit worse than "just fine".

Answer (score -1):

“Just fine” can mean “As well as I wish”.

If I choose to completely ignore the subject than that is “Just fine” by me.
Conversely, it can mean “We are great friends”.
It describes a range of attitudes and is therefore an obtuse statement.

It reflects the non aggressive or take it or leave it attitude to the relationship.